# Can we fix this typo?

Tags: discussion, editing

Browsing about, I stumbled upon [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/3113/1308), which has this snippet:

> British **prim minister** William Pitt the Younger

-- an obvious typo.

So I attempted to make the site better by [suggesting an edit](https://history.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/1613) (Note that I had to make a minor improvement to the punctuation and also remove a superfluous word, to get the minimum character requirement.)

The [suggesting edit](https://history.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/1613) was rejected, **can somebody please fix that typo?**

Comment: The reason behind my rejection is that the edit was quite minor. If you're going to edit, make it substantial. The typo was the only problem in the post. Adding the commas is grammatically incorrect; "The younger" is part of his title. Removing the word "now" is just a matter of style, not necessary at all. After looking it over, I decided to reject it for the reasons previously stated.

Comment: @Luke - I think part of the problem here is that, IIRC, the edit software doesn't let you just make a 1-character edit if your rep is low enough to require a review. That clearly (at least in this case) encourages unessecary changes.

Comment: @Luke - The original post had the name listed as "William Pittthe Younger", which in itself should have been enough justification for making the edit. Because the word "the" was running on with "Pitt", it could cause people to assume that the middle name was "Pittthe" and the last name was "Younger". There were multiple edits required, which means this suggested edit was valid. Thanks for fixing it T.E.D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went in and added the wayward trailing `e` causing all the controversy. Sadly, trailing `e`s are tough to com by, so I had to retroactively remov this one from the [Unix file creation command](http://linux.die.net/man/2/creat). Hopefully nobody notices...

Comment: Thnks T..D..​‌​‌​ ;)

Comment: @T.E.D I was about to chang your answer, then I laughed.